# TaskQueueSample.java : Code 403

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pull-queue

I am trying to make the sample works so here is the code :

[Sample Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout?repo=samples)

The documentation for the installation is there:

[Installation documentation](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/taskqueue-cmdline-sample/instructions.html)

I had a little problem on the step:

> Click on "API Access", and then on "Create an OAuth 2.0 Client
>   ID...".  Enter a product name and click "Next".

The UI of the console has been upgraded probably so I use those data for the authentication in the console:
[image]

Then I run the program and it brings me to the webpage to allow the app and then i got the following error message in the console:

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "you are not allowed to make this api call"
  } ],
  "message" : "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
```

My queue.xml ACL is set with the email i used to authenticate

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the native TaskQueue-API from the GAE Java SDK? You don't need to set up credentials, connection, ... .

You can see an example on the [GAE Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull) - here a Pull Queue, but you can also use a Push Queue if you want (an example is also in the GAE Docs).

Which one of the examples do you want to launch on the google app engine? On your posted link are many examples available :) . Tell me if you really want to use the Google-API to access the TaskQueues.

Comment: it is not a program launched on gae but a third party and the example is the one in the title of my question

Comment: The example is called `taskqueue-cmdline-sample`, the title is the mainly used class of the example with this [URL](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/taskqueue-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/taskqueue/cmdline/TaskQueueSample.java?repo=samples) . Have you set APPLICATION_NAME in this class and updated your json credentials file?

Comment: Have you debugged your application and checked the REST-call? Is it correct? Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/vPyO0EiaKys/ch9jfUhbHfYJ.) can help you?